# Erorres con material design y android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo el android studio 3.2.1, sincronize el material design con la siguiente version: implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0, cuando inserto un: 
me sale error no se que hacer si hay respuesta le agradeceria

asi esta el Build.gradle en mi pc:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig{
        applicationId"miscelanea2018.daniel.miscelanea2018"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    } buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt '), ' proguard - rules.pro '
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Recorda instalar las herramientas del SDK 28, anda al SDK manager en `Tools - SDK Manager`
e instala lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]